How can I simplify $\prod_\limits{n=1\atop n\ne m}^{a}\frac{nx - 1}{n - m}:\ ? $
I ran into the following product while doing a Lagrange Polynomial Interpolation for a math puzzle I created for myself and am struggling to simplify it further:
$$
\prod_{\Large n = 1\atop \Large n \ne m}^{a}
\frac{nx - 1}{n - m}
$$
Without the $n\ne m$ part, $\tt WolframAlpha$ gives me:
$$
\prod_{\Large n = 1 \atop\Large n \ne m}^{a}
\frac{nx-1}{n-m} =
\frac{x^{a}\,\Gamma\left(1 - m\right)\Gamma\left(1 + a - x^{-1}\right)}{\Gamma\left(1 + a - m\right)
\Gamma\left(1 - x^{-1}\right)}
$$

This does not work though ( not unexpected ) because $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and I know
$\Gamma\left(\mathbb{-N}\right) =
\text{undefined}$. I am sure there are more problems with this formula but that one was the easiest for me to find.
I do know how to even attempt to evaluate this product with the $n \ne m$ because I have not taken a math course high enough to evaluate even simple products let alone ones like this.


Edit: I am also looking through this book I found, Table of Integrals, Series, and Products (PDF link via archive.org) but haven't found anything helpful yet.

Why do you say $m \in \mathbb{Z}$? $m$ is not necessarily positive?

@温泽海 My bad, should it be $\mathbb{N}$? $m$ is always positive.

$\mathbb{N}$ usually means all non-negative integers, which includes $0$. In your case, you can either write $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ or say in word $m$ is a positive integer or say $m \in {1, \ldots, a}$.

Some people use $\Bbb N$ to mean nonnegative integers, but many others (including most number theorists) use $\Bbb N$ to mean positive integers.

But I don't understand why cannot you just divide the formula given by wolframalpha by the $m$ term?

@GregMartin Good catch! I fixed it

@温泽海 Perhaps my desmos graph will help? I did not explain the entire problem in the post because I didn't want any hints past this part of it. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ug7z1thl1b

Assuming $m>0$ and $a>m$
Denominator
$$\prod\limits_{n=1, n\ne m}^a (n-m)=\prod\limits_{n=1}^{m-1} (n-m)\prod\limits_{n=m+1}^{a} (n-m)$$
Using Pochhammer symbols
$$\prod\limits_{n=1}^{m-1} (n-m)=(1-m)_{m-1}=(-1)^{m+1}\, (1)_{m-1}=(-1)^{m+1}\,\Gamma(m)$$
$$\prod\limits_{n=m+1}^{a} (n-m)=\Gamma (a-m+1)$$
Recombining
$$\text{denominator}=\prod\limits_{n=1, n\ne m}^a (n-m)=(-1)^{m+1}\,\Gamma(m)\,\Gamma (a-m+1)$$
Numerator
$$\prod\limits_{n=1, n\ne m}^a (n x-1)=\prod\limits_{n=1}^{m-1} (n x-1) \prod\limits_{n=m+1}^{a} (n x-1)$$
$$\prod\limits_{n=1}^{m-1} (n x-1) =x^{m-1}  \left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)_{m-1}=-\frac{x^m \Gamma
   \left(m-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\Gamma\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)}$$
$$\prod\limits_{n=m+1}^{a} (n x-1)=x^{a-m}
   \left(m-\frac{1}{x}+1\right)_{a-m}=\frac{x^{a-m}\, \Gamma
   \left(a-\frac{1}{x}+1\right)}{\Gamma \left(m-\frac{1}{x}+1\right)}$$
Recombining (assuming $x\neq \frac 1m$)
$$\text{numerator}=\prod\limits_{n=1, n\ne m}^a (n x-1)=\frac{x^a \,\Gamma
   \left(a-\frac{1}{x}+1\right)}{(m x-1) \Gamma \left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)}$$
Therefore
$$\large\color{blue}{\prod_\limits{n=1\atop n\ne m}^{a}\frac{nx - 1}{n - m}=(-1)^{m+1}\,\frac{x^a \,\Gamma\left(a-\frac{1}{x}+1\right)}{(mx-1)\, \Gamma (m)\, \Gamma\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)\, \Gamma(a-m+1)}}$$

First of all, WolframAlpha was wrong in that it didn't understand the condition $n\ne m$: what's true is
$$
\prod_{n=1}^a \biggl(\frac{nx-1}{n-z}\biggr) = \frac{x^{a}\Gamma(1-z)\Gamma(1+a-x^{-1})}{\Gamma(1+a-z)\Gamma(1-x^{-1})}
$$
for any complex $z$. Therefore
\begin{align*}
\prod_{\substack{1\le n\le a \\ n\ne m}} \biggl(\frac{nx-1}{n-z}\biggr) &= \frac{x^{a}\Gamma(1-z)\Gamma(1+a-x^{-1})}{\Gamma(1+a-z)\Gamma(1-x^{-1})} \bigg/ \frac{mx-1}{m-z} \\
&= \frac{x^{a}\Gamma(1+a-x^{-1})}{\Gamma(1+a-z)\Gamma(1-x^{-1})(mx-1)} (m-z)\Gamma(1-z),
\end{align*}
and so
\begin{align*}
\prod_{\substack{1\le n\le a \\ n\ne m}} \biggl(\frac{nx-1}{n-m}\biggr) &= \lim_{z\to m} \prod_{\substack{1\le n\le a \\ n\ne m}} \biggl(\frac{nx-1}{n-z}\biggr) \\
&= \frac{x^{a}\Gamma(1+a-x^{-1})}{\Gamma(1+a-m)\Gamma(1-x^{-1})(mx-1)} \lim_{z\to m} (m-z)\Gamma(1-z) \\
&= \frac{x^{a}\Gamma(1+a-x^{-1})}{(a-m)!\Gamma(1-x^{-1})(mx-1)} \lim_{z\to m} (m-z)\Gamma(1-z).
\end{align*}
The last limit can be calculated from the known residues of the Gamma function at its poles, yielding
\begin{align*}
\prod_{\substack{1\le n\le a \\ n\ne m}} \biggl(\frac{nx-1}{n-m}\biggr) &= \frac{x^{a}\Gamma(1+a-x^{-1})}{(a-m)!\Gamma(1-x^{-1})(mx-1)} \frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}.
\end{align*}

$$P_m:=\prod\limits_{n=1, n\ne m}^a (n-m)= (m-1)! (a-m)!(-1)^{m-1}$$
Proof:- for fixed $m$ the first $m-1$ numbers in the product are $(1-m )(2-m)\dots 1 = (-1)^{m-1}(m-1)!$ then the rest numbers in the product are $1(2)(3) \dots (a-m)= (a-m)!$
$p_x:= \prod\limits_{n=1, n\ne m}^a (nx-1)=\frac{1}{mx-1}\prod\limits_{n=1}^a (nx-1)$ (assuming $x \ne 1/m$).
$$p_x=\frac{x^{a} (-1)^a}{mx-1} \prod \left(\frac{1}{x}-n\right)=\frac{x^{a} (-1)^a}{mx-1}\cdot \frac{\left(\frac 1 x -1 \right)!}{\left(\frac 1 x -1 -a\right)!}  $$
Assuming of course $x\ne 1/n$ or the product equals zero
Now what if $x=1/m$
$$p_{1/m}= \left[\left(\frac{1}{m}-1\right)\left(\frac{2}{m}-1\right)\left(\frac{3}{m}-1\right)\dots \left(\frac{m-1}{m}-1\right) \right]\cdot\left[\left(\frac{m+1}{m}-1\right)\left(\frac{m+2}{m}-1\right)\left(\frac{m+3}{m}-1\right)\left(\frac{a}{m}-1\right)\right]=\frac{(-1)^{m-1}a!}{m^{a-1}}$$
Now your product is $f(x,m):=\frac{p_x}{p_m}$
$$ f(x,m) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{{x^{a} (-1)^{a-m+1}}\cdot {\left(\frac 1 x -1 \right)!}}{(mx-1)(m-1)! (a-m)!\left(\frac 1 x -1 -a\right)!},  & xm \ne 1 \\
\frac{{a!}}{(m-1)! (a-m)!m^{a-1}},  & xm=1
\\
0, & xn=1 \text{ for } n\ne m 
\end{cases}$$
